# Angular: get changes from input()

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

I have a component named ftn-popin-opener

```
<label>{{ selectedValue }}</label>
```

where selectedValue is an Input()

```
@Input() selectedValue: string;
```

Inside another component where I use the ftn-popin-opener, I would like to detect every time when the Input() selectedValue changes:

```
<ftn-popin-opener
   [selectedValue]='professionalSituation | titlecase'>
</ftn-popin-opener>
```

I tried with ngOnChanges() but does not work

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    console.log(changes.professionalSituation.currentValue);
  }
```

Comment: You want to detect changes in `ftn-popin-opener` component right? Can you please post your `ftn-popin-opener` component's code here?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how `professionalSituation` is handle in your parent component, but, what you could do in your `ftn-popin-opener` component is having an `@Input` setter like this:

```js
export class FtnPopinOpenerComponent {
  myValue!: string;
 
  @Input() set selectedValue(value: string) {
     this.myValue = value;
  }
}
```

In your template HTML:

```html
<label>{{ myValue }}</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ngOnChanges life cycle method in the component where there is @Input, in your case you have to use it in popin-opener component